# Strange readings from sensor

Tags: c++, string, cout

My program is consisting of image processing (OpenCV) and proximity sensor (Arduino UNO). Basically it detects an object and measure its distance before calculates the object's size and shape.

I'm trying to improve my program performance by using `cout` instead of `printf` when taking readings from the proximity sensor. Below are the programs:

**MAIN PROGRAM**

```
int main(void){
  int j;

  /*used for port"COM2"*/
  HANDLE hCom=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

  char input[30];
  string ss,ss1,ss2,ss3;

  /*Open "COM2"*/
  hCom=CreateFile("COM2",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

  if(hCom==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf("can't open file");
  }
  DCB dcb;
  memset(&dcb,0,sizeof (DCB));
  dcb.DCBlength=sizeof (DCB);
  dcb.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
  dcb.ByteSize=8;
  dcb.Parity=NOPARITY;
  dcb.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
  SetCommState(hCom,&dcb);

  while(1){
    // OpenCV stuffs
    // Sensor readings AKA printout <-- THIS PART!
  }
}
```

Tested commands in `THIS PART!`:

**BEFORE**

```
    if(hCom!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwBytes=0;
        j=ReadFile(hCom,&input,18,&dwBytes,NULL);
        if(j==1)
        {       
            ss=input;
            ss1=ss.substr(0,6);
            ss2=ss.substr(6,6);
            ss3=ss.substr(12,6);
        }
    }

    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            printf("%c", ss[j]);
        }
```

Results: 1-2 fps with OpenCV

[image: OK-ish slowpoke result]

**AFTER**

```
    if(hCom!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwBytes=0;
        j=ReadFile(hCom,&input,6,&dwBytes,NULL);
        if(j==1)
        {       
            cout << input;
        }
    }
```

Results: 15-20ish fps with OpenCV

[image: Weird characters]

My question is **how to eliminate the random characters [`THIS?` in AFTER pic] between the readings?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to initialize 'input' with zeros?

Comment: Where is your minimal example?

Comment: @Eugene Welp I can't believe I missed that. Problems solved. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dwBytes` has the bytes actually read. It is very likely that the sensor does not terminate the string `input` being read with a null byte, because of which `cout` is printing garbage.

What you can do is to explicitly set `input[dwBytes] = '\0'` before you call `cout`.